# Call fails when I send 2 params to other contract with abi?

Tags: solidity, abi, abi.encodewithsignature

I can send 1 parameter to Contract A (otherContract) and it works well. But when I send 2 parameters, it fails. What do I do wrong?

**Contract A:**

```
function sumTwoParams (uint256 _num1, uint256 _num2) pure public returns (uint256) {
        return _num1 + _num2;
    }
```

**Contract B:**

```
function sumTwoParams (uint256 _num1, uint256 _num2) public {     
        bytes memory payload = abi.encodeWithSignature("sumTwoParams(uint256, uint256)", _num1, _num2);
        (bool success, bytes memory returnData) = otherContract.call(payload);
        require(success, "Failed!");
        
        (sumResult) = abi.decode(returnData, (uint256));
    }
```

**sumResult** is a member of Contract B, tx reverts at `require(success, "Failed!");` in Contract B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `"sumTwoParams(uint256,uint256)"` (no whitespaces after `,`) when encoding the signature.

Comment: Oh my lord! Thanks a lot! That solved my headache! :D

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are adding an space to the signature parameters, hence, it produces a different signature.

Take a look at this code:

```js
function encodeWithSignatureWithSpaceInParams() public pure returns(bytes memory) {
        // This produces: 0x60fb6acb00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002
        return abi.encodeWithSignature("sumTwoParams(uint256, uint256)", 1, 2);
    }

    function encodeWithSignatureWithoutSpaceInParams() public pure returns(bytes memory) {
        // This produces: 0xff19a36e00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002
        return abi.encodeWithSignature("sumTwoParams(uint256,uint256)", 1, 2);
    }
```

Remove the space. It should be like `sumTwoParams(uint256,uint256)`